# Oracle database: want to check privileges that I gave to the users

Tags: oracle, database-management

I create some users (c##U100, c##U101, c##U102, c##U103, c##U104) to practice grant privilege command, and my authorization graph is as follow:
[authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39dmC.png)

my professor asks me to test the privileges using those commands:

```html
col owner format a20
col table_name format a15
col privilege format a10
col grantee format a10

SELECT owner,privilege,table_name,grantee
  FROM sys.dba_tab_privs
 WHERE grantee like 'c##U1%'
 ORDER BY grantee, table_name, privilege;
```

But it doesn't work, it returns "No rows selected". Kind of wondering if there's something wrong with my previous steps or with this piece of code... Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you successfully granted privileges to those users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User names are always in upper case; capitalize the 'c' in your query.

```
SELECT owner,privilege,table_name,grantee
  FROM sys.dba_tab_privs
 WHERE grantee like 'C##U1%'
 ORDER BY grantee, table_name, privilege;
```

Comment: You're welcome. If that's the case, please accept the answer. 